# Java Error in Flutter - Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

Today while compiling a project Flutter, it gave me this error. As I understand it is a Java problem.

- Java JDK 11 is installed on the PC,
- but Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to see it.

Searching on the internet I didn't find how to do it (or maybe I didn't understand). Thanks to those who will be able to help me.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your settings, code & errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!
Try to add this line in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.3.1
```

N.B: "jdk-17.0.3.1" here give your jdk version number